# Not able to compile Syslog-ng 3.8.1 on RHEL 8.5. Getting error message after issuing "make". Anyone have this issue?

Tags: makefile, syslog-ng

I have installed the dependencies before building syslog-ng from source. However, I'm getting the compiling error below:

```
make --no-print-directory all-recursive
  CC       lib/lib_libsyslog_ng_la-tlscontext.lo
lib/tlscontext.c: In function 'tls_session_verify':
lib/tlscontext.c:140:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'X509_STORE_CTX' {aka 'struct x509_store_ctx_st'}
   if (ok && ctx->error_depth == 0 && !tls_session_verify_fingerprint(ctx))
                ^~
lib/tlscontext.c: In function 'tls_context_setup_session':
lib/tlscontext.c:313:48: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 'SSL_CTX' {aka 'struct ssl_ctx_st'}
       X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_flags(self->ssl_ctx->param, verify_flags);
                                                ^~
lib/tlscontext.c: In function 'tls_verify_certificate_name':
lib/tlscontext.c:554:19: warning: 'ASN1_STRING_data' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                   guchar *dnsname = ASN1_STRING_data(gen_name->d.dNSName);
                   ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:15,
                 from lib/tlscontext.h:29,
                 from lib/tlscontext.c:24:
/usr/include/openssl/asn1.h:554:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(unsigned char *ASN1_STRING_data(ASN1_STRING *x))
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [Makefile:9325: lib/lib_libsyslog_ng_la-tlscontext.lo] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:13207: all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:5434: all] Error 2
```

Comment: I'd say you have the wrong version of OpenSSL.  Either the code wants a 1.1.x version and you have the 3.x version installed, or vice versa.

Comment: Are you set on building syslog-ng yourself?  You can get pre-packaged syslog-ng 3.23.1 from EPEL.